# Gmail don't show email markup using Go-To Actions

Tags: google-schemas

I'm trying to implement in my emails "Go-To Actions" but didn't worked. I tried both json-ld and microdata but noone of them works... any clues?

I send my emails from postMarkApp but in source email code it shows correctly the action (in json-ld and microdata)

Example of markup (copy of google documentation):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "action": {
      "@type": "ViewAction",
      "url": "http://www.onfan.com/es/explore",
      "name": "Recomiéndale un restaurante"
      },
"description": "Recomienda a tu amigo un restaurante"
}
</script>
```

thanks.

Joan

Comment: hi, did you manage to make it work send from to your own email?

Comment: no... but I left the project... so I didn't check anymore...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the markup is valid. However have you registered with Google before you send emails to other users from the link below?

https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/registering-with-google

Or you just for testing purposes by sending emails to yourself.

Comment: yes.. exactly.. I didn't realize that exists this form!